# Populate a formula down a column until no more data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to populate a column with the formula "=today()" in column B until there is no more data in the rows.  There is about 650 rows of data but I am creating a macro that will have to work if there were more or less rows of data.  How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Start by knowing how to get the last row [HERE](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/10/02/find-last-row-in-an-excel-sheetvbavb-net/). Then explore using the `.Formula` or `.FormulaR1C1` Range Object Property.

Answer (score 0):

Sub columndate()

Dim NoRowsCount as integer

NoRowsCount = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i= 0 to NoRowsCount

```
If Activesheet.Cells(A, i).value <> "" then

   Activesheet.Cells(B, i).value = Today()

end if
```

i = i+1

Next

End Sub